# Export animated modifiers to glTF

Tags: modifiers, export, gltf

I animated a bending tree using the Simple Deform (Bend) modifier. It works well within blender 2.81 but i cannot export it into a .gltf file.

How can i do this using shape keys or something?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=+glTF+shape+keys

Comment: Not sure, but the workflow described here might do it: https://blenderartists.org/t/export-bezier-curve-animation-as-gltf-and-or-fbx/1151423/4?u=donmccurdy